# Image Source in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: image, user-controls, windows-phone-8

I am creating an user control which has an image within it. The image has a build action = content.

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/Pic.png"/>
```

The above code is not working within the user control. The same code works well when the Image is placed within a PhonePage. Any pointers on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is having a hard time with the path especially if the user control XAML isn't in the same directory as the phone page XAML. You may need to traverse a bit like this: `../Assets/Images/Pic.png` You can also try moving Pic.png to the same directory and setting the source to `Pic.png`